# Can I autorefresh an Excel file using java or any API?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an Excel file store locally which contains some sheets in it, one sheet containing raw data and other sheets contain performance pivots/graphs generated based on raw data.

The raw data sheet of an excel file is generated from my java program. I am storing the program generated raw data into the excel file stored locally.

1. Is there any way to refresh this excel file so that the related pivots/graphs on another sheets in same excel file gets refreshed to the new/updated raw data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either side, in Excel or in Java... does it matter exactly when the Excel file gets refreshed?

If you can write VBA, you can have your Java program output the data into a data file, and when the Excel is next opened, the macro inside will copy the data and perform any necessary calculations.

If you want to do it via Java, you can use Apache POI:
https://poi.apache.org/

If Apache POI doesn't work for you, Excel exposes itself as an ActiveX object, you can use JNI or 3rd party Java-to-COM bridges to make changes to the Excel file.